# Building topology in C++ using ns3

Tags: c++, ns-3

Could anyone please tell me why I get this message after running my program for building topology in ns3.24?

```
assert failed. cond="c.GetN () == 2", file=../src/point-to-point/helper/point-to-point-helper.cc, line=220
terminate called without an active exception
```

Thank you.

Comment: Learn your debugger. Use your debugger. Love your debugger.

Comment: It's a bit too hard for us to know how it happens to be `c.GetN() == 2` or not, without looking at a single line of your code...

Comment: Please post an example based on the guidelines [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the nodes number, to install the pointTopoint it must be done in two nodes. Like below:

nodes.Create(2)

If you are trying to install in a different numbers of nodes it can cause this error.

BR,